# Is there any recognition for having 100 StackExchange accounts?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, user-accounts

So, is there any recognition for being a member on a hundred different SE sites? A badge or something?

Just checking, as I noticed my profile says 100 accounts and I was wondering.

Comment: What's the point?

Comment: Just a sorry nod and a passing thought about people needing a life.

Comment: I was just wondering. No point really. Then again, there are lots of badges that don't seem to serve a useful purpose, like "10 answers that were accepted, but not upvoted". So why not a badge for "visited so and so many SE sites"

Comment: here's an idea, how about a medal for getting up to X rep on Y different accounts

Comment: Badges are given for behavior we like to see more of - that is, behavior that is helping the user and the community. Apply that to the above.

Comment: @MrLister: That's a consolation prize. Anyway, while I kind of like the sentiment of rewarding participation on many sites, there's something you don't answer- which site would that badge be given on?

Comment: If we were talking about _participation_ on 100 sites, I guess there would be something to talk about. Having registered on 100 sites doesn't show anything about your participation.

Comment: @DavidRobinson That's a good one. I nominate meta.stackoverflow.com, since it has a special status (i.e. not specifically for meta questions about SO).

Comment: @Mat True, true. If we only look at sites I've got more than 101 rep on, that's not that many. Oh well.

Comment: @Oded - you're an employee now - not sure your overlords will like that comment, even though it did make me laugh :)

Comment: @AdamRackis Which of Oded's comments are you addressing?

Comment: @Adam - the overlords can delete that comment. And I'd like to think they would agree with the sentiment.

Comment: @MrLister - the first, and please know I was mostly joking.

Comment: Oh man, I thought you meant 100 different *Stack Overflow* accounts and I was about to "recognize" you.  100 SE accounts is much better.  ;)

Comment: @Bill Well, that sort of recognition *does* show up prominently on their profile!

Comment: @Bill - `for(int i = 1; i < accounts.Length; i++) accounts[i].mergeWith(accounts[i - 1]);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

nah! bad idea.. practically you won't be participating in all 100 accounts.

Just creating an account (hardly active) won't contribute anything to the sites..

This proposed badge would only encourage people to create accounts in sites which they may not visit again! causing burden over sites..
In your own case you haven't posted a single Q or A in more than 90 sites (approx)

So NOPE!

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't. Nor there should be really. What's the point? It isn't a "positive" or "constructive" thing you've done.

### Useful links

- **[A summerised list of all badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges)**
- **[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)**

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two issues you would have to address before such a badge could even be considered:

1. Which site would the badge be given on? (All of them? The one where your rep is highest?)
2. On all but 11 of your accounts, you've never asked or answered a question (and on the vast majority of them you've never even earned a badge, and thus never voted). If someone should be rewarded for contributing to many sites, surely there'd have to be some threshold to which they *actually contributed.* (Otherwise you'd just be encouraging people to visit site after site after site, grinding away just to get the badge/reward, and not actually adding anything to the network).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look at badges, check out

https://stackoverflow.com/badges

That has a list of the badges on SO and their criteria.

As for recognition for having 100 accounts, yes, it exists.  It's that number `100` above your short list of accounts on your profile, to the left of the string that says `Accounts`